# Mongodb aggregation remove accents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there any possibility to remove accents from specific field in project stage or any other aggregation stage?

My input document looks like this:

```
{
   "title" : "Está comprometido",
   "value" : "3"
},
```

And I need this output:

```
{
   "title" : "Esta_comprometido",
   "value" : "3"
},
```

Comment: What about the underscore character?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It doesn't matter, I know how to add the underscore. The problem is how to remove accents. If you can provide a solution please feel free to answer

Comment: Do you have the possibility to do this change somewhere else in the client? String related functions are not very strong in MongoDB.

Comment: I thought maybe there could be any clean and elegant solution in aggregation framework to do this. The fact is that In next step I need to use this title value as object key and "value" as object value.

Like: { "Esta_comprometido": 3}

Comment: Well, **finding** such documents is rather simple with `$regex` or `$regexFindAll`. However, in order to modify them you have to write a lot of ugly code with `$substrCP`, `$concat`, `$indexOfCP`, etc. Maybe better use JavaScript or something else for that.

Comment: I hope in next mongodb version will add string features. Thanks in advance @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @WernfriedDomscheit suggestion. I finally solved the issue using client postprocessing. I'm using javascript as client

Here I post a jsbin example of how I solved this:

https://jsbin.com/kecikomuja/edit?html,js,output

I'm ussing `normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")` to replace accents

This stackoverflow post gave me the idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/6329540